# Why wouldn't this html stop loading?

Tags: html, input

I noticed when I added this line to my html file, the page won't stop loading. Why? And how do I fix this?

```
<input type="image" onload="this.src='done.bmp'" src="Loading.bmp" >
```

[Loading.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7UUq.png)
[Done.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEagM.png)

Comment: It's because when you change `this.src`, that loads another image and immediately runs `onload` again.  You need more sophisticated javascript to handle this.

Comment: Do you have NoScript or some other Javascript-blocking extension "helping"?

Comment: Why not use img tag? You can use a function to detect when a page is done loading and then change the image src.

Comment: @Joel I was testing the `onload` attribute in the `input` tag

Comment: @AlwaysLearning also, what is the extension "helping"?

Comment: "helping" as in "getting in the way and preventing local Javascript from running" which is the default state of extensions like NoScript.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Oh, no.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use

```
window.stop();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop

Comment: It a solution, but not really.